# How to make sed ignore slash and backslash

Tags: bash, sed, backslash, slash

Okay: first of all I did try searching for answers before posting this one. I'm not saying, that there are none, I'm just saying, that I was unable to find one. To my defense: I've been forced to switch from scripting and other interesting work into working as a grocery shop assistant, so my brain probably rotted away.

What I'm trying to do is the following:

I have a file which contains, let's say, descriptions of goods including EAN codes. There are no proper delimiters. I only have "column lengths". I know, that EAN code column starts at the position 134 and ends at the position 147.

I tried using this:

`cat $processedFile | sed "s/^(.{134})/\1;/g" | sed "s/^(.{148})/\1;/g >> $outFile`

- reason being, that I'm trying to make sure, that the EAN code is placed between two semicolons for further processing. Worked almost perfectly.

My problem is this:

Since people working with the software which generates the files are extremely computer mistrusting don't really care what they use when naming goods. Therefore some items contain slash or backslash as a part of their name, which is then another column in the file, incidentally right in front of the EAN.

Some columns therefore remain unprocessed.

Example of the input file:

`00110363       201406170014469  35.0    1    35.000              0.2360                0.3720       T   SnackName001  chees-onion8588004269750   0291410610363          0                 0.00.000
    00110363       201406170013935  24.0    1    24.000              0.2780                0.4320       T   SnackName002  blah-blah-b78588000510535   0291410610363          0                 0.00.000
    00110363       201406170013936  24.0    1    24.000              0.2780                0.4320       T   SnackName003  blah-blah-b78588000510511   0291410610363          0                 0.00.000
    00110363       201406170016056  18.0    1    18.000              0.2033                0.3520       T   SnackName004  blah-blah  3838700069938   0291410610363          0                 0.00.000
    00110363       201406170013808  10.0    1    10.000              0.5794                0.9220       T   SnackName005  blah-blah-b8588000467617   0291410610363          0                 0.00.000
    00110363       201406170009326   8.0    5    40.000              0.7500                1.2120       T   Sugar powd. brandN\ED1kg    8594003782411   0291410610363          0                 0.00.000`

The last 3-line is an example of what causes me headaches.

Any hints? Or... would it be better to use something entirely different from sed?

I need to make sure, that the scripts are idiot-proof since I expect that people who have difficulties to find the power button on the chassis will be working with them later on.

EDIT: I apologize, I didn't realize, that EANs aren't so easily distinguishable in my example ^_^; , thank you, condorwasabi .

EAN code is the Integer following string names. To be more precise: 
in 

    `00110363       201406170014469  35.0    1    35.000              0.2360                0.3720       T   SnackName001  chees-onion8588004269750   0291410610363          0                 0.00.000`

the `8588004269750` is the EAN part. And yes, in the file, if the name is too long, there is no space, colon, semicolon or any other character to mark the end of the name and the beginning of the EAN code.

Comment: So you're trying to extract the EAN numbers and put them in a file separated by semicolons? Could you tell what the EAN numbers are in the input file you posted?

Comment: As added in the edit: SnackName001  chees-onion8588004269750

the 8588004269750 is the EAN

Comment: Hmm... I think I might consider writing a Java application which will do all the work, since this is just the first step in about 4 and it's taking me too much time... T_T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using `awk`.

I'm not fully clear on the requirements, but this may get you started:

```
awk '{ 
    cleanLine=substr($0,1)
    gsub(/\\[A-Z]{2}/, "", cleanLine)
    EAN=substr(cleanLine, 134, 13)
    sub(EAN, ";" EAN ";")
    print
 }' file
```

- Temporarily creates a cleaned-up version of the input line with sequences such as `\ED` removed - any sequence of `\` followed by two uppercase letters. You also mention `/` in your question - not sure what patterns to look for there, but the resulting regex must replace `/\\[A-Z]{2}/` above.
  NOTE:

  - Here I assume that cleaning up simply means *removing* these sequences - if, on the other hand, they each represent a *specific number of original characters*, replace the `""` argument to `gsub()` with a string composed of that number of *dummy characters*, e.g., `"x"`.
  - The assumption is that *all* such sequences are extraneous sequences to be removed.
- Extracts the EAN from the cleaned-up line by character positions.
- Replaces the EAN in the *original* line with the EAN enclosed in ";" and prints the result.

  - Note that this assumes that the EAN doesn't also appear *before* column 134 in the input file.